# How to stop adb shell from echoing every command?

Tags: android, windows, adb

On Windows 7 X64, `adb shell` (run from `cmd.exe`) repeats every command that I enter:

```
>adb shell
root@flame:/ # pwd
pwd
/
```

When I connect from Linux, this problem does not occur.

I tried with a Lenovo tablet running Android 4.2.2, and with a [Flame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Phone_guide/Flame) running the latest Firefox OS nightly. Firefox OS is built on top of Android's HAL, which explains why it is possible to connect by `adb`.

`adb` version on both systems: 1.0.32

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD.Exe, you wasted more of my money. If you are typing into any other program other than CMD then CMD has nothing to do with it. If you double click something to start your program CMD isn't even loaded. Consoles don't mean CMD is involved. Consoles don't require CMD.